# Array to string conversion error in Yii2 console app

Tags: yii2

Please tell me such a thing. There is a self-written site, the code works on it, when I transfer the same code to the yii2 console application, it will get an error converting an array to a string

I will describe in more detail what is happening.

There is a text file inside which the following.

```
5|02.10.2020 20:20|Name 1
5|02.10.2020 22:25|Name 2
```

Day of the week, date and time, program name. It is necessary to add this case to the database.

```
    $data = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", file_get_contents( './import/' . $filename . '.txt' ) );
    $tv = explode("\n", $data);

    foreach ($tv as $line)
    {
    $ex1 = explode("|",$line);
    $ex2 = explode(" ",$ex1[1]);
    ... next insert to db $ex1[0] - day of week, $ex2[0] - date, $ex2[1] - time, $ex1[2] - name
    }
```

In a regular .php file, all this works, and when the same code is in yii2, it swears at conversion. Why is that? How to do it right?

It turns out that it cannot use $ ex1 [0], $ ex2 [0] and so on as a string.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have empty line at the end of this file?

Comment: yes, the first and last line in the file contains a different format. because of this, the error occurs.